# Cómo puedo comprobar si en SQL Server existe un inicio de sesión, con código de VB.NET

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

O sea, en Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio se visualiza:
Seguridad\Inicios de sesión\sa

Si creo otro inicio de sesión, por ejemplo: MiSesion, también aparecería en esa lista.

La pregunta es cómo puedo (con código de VB.NET) comprobar si el objeto MiSesion está creado (ojo, no quiero saber si está iniciada o no la sesión, sino si el objeto está definido o creado), de manera que si no está, lo pueda crear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes realizar una consulta a la base de datos a [sys.sql_logins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-sql-logins-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) o a la manera antigua [sys.syslogins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-syslogins-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Ejemplos

```
SELECT * from sys.sql_logins
```

```
select * from syslogins
```

Comment: Muchas gracias.